# How to print subtitles while video is playing (on sync) using python?

Tags: python, moviepy, python-vlc

I'm trying to print a text in parallel to video playing like the meaning of the subtitles.
I stuck at how to print the subtitles while the video is playing. Actually based on the video frame it's printing but I need to print the respective text like the .srt file synchronizes with video.

I tried this

```
while media_player.is_playing():
       value = media_player.video_get_spu_description()
       print(value)
```

But I couldn't find it useful. By using start and end times and some sleep conditions I think I can sync somewhat.

Kindly help me with this.

Comment: Are you asking about playing a video with subtitles (from an `.srt` file), or do your want to print the subtitles in the console using print?

Comment: Thanks, @Rotem for ur reply. I want to print subtitle in console while video playing